# Get Notification when all threads finish work

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am new to threading concept, using threading first time in my application. One of my application processing multiple data, without threading it is taking approx 2 minutes while with help of threading it is taking just 25 seconds, but i want notification when all threads finishes work.

```
  private int z = 0 ; 

 startfunction()
  {
   z= 250;
    start1step(z);

  }

  private void start1step(int i)
  {
     if (i < 0)
            return;
        else
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
            thread.Start();

            start1step( --i);

        }

    }

   public void WorkThreadFunction( )
    {
        try
        {
          int x = z ; 
           z-- ;
           // do some background work
         if(x ==0)
         MessageBox.Show("All Thread finished");
        }      
        catch
         {
            //
         } 
     }
```

Above sample code is working perfectly except that notification part, I want notification when all threads finishes background work. There is one last step left which sums up work finished by all these threads.

Please help

Comment: Which version of .net?

Comment: As Sriram noted, my answer assumes that simply waiting is sufficient "notification" for your needs. If you can be more specific about what kind of notification you actually want, I would be happy to adjust my answer to suit.

Comment: Consider fine tuning the number of threads you are using. If your "background work" does not involve any external resources (DB, file system, network communication, ...), you are likely to get the best performance when the number of threads is close to the number of CPU cores you have. Much higher number of threads may actually worsen the performance (marginally :))

Comment: @PeterDuniho, my requirement is , i have to call once function after these thread finishes their work. So where shall i call them in your answer. Many thanks for your helping and kind Approach.

Comment: @NidhiSharma: as asked before, what version of .NET are you using? The simplest approach is the `async`/`await` pattern, but that's only available in .NET 4.5. There are still good options in previous versions though. Also, you haven't explained in what context you call the `startfunction()` method; if that's being called in the main UI thread, you definitely won't to make that method wait for the threads to finish (that would cause your user interface to stop working while the threads work), but if it's being called in some other context, you can call your function at the end of that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. I would say the two most convenient methods that remain similar to your current implementation involve using a `CountDownEvent` or switching to the `Task` class for your threading. A third method involves using the `Parallel.ForEach()` method, and that might actually suit your specific scenario better.

`CountDownEvent` looks like this:

```
CountDownEvent countDown = new CountDownEvent(250);

startfunction()
{
    countDown.Reset();
    start1step(250);
    countDown.Wait();
}

private void start1step(int i)
{
    while (i-- > 0)
    {
        new Thread(WorkThreadFunction, i).Start();
    }
}

public void WorkThreadFunction(object o)
{
    int x = (int)o;

    try
    {
        // do some background work
    }      
    catch
    {
        //
    } 
    finally
    {
        countDown.Signal();
    }
}
```

`Task` looks like this:

```
startfunction()
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[250];
    start1step(tasks);
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}

private void start1step(Task[] tasks)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        int taskParam = i;

        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => WorkThreadFunction(taskParam));
    }
}

public void WorkThreadFunction(int x)
{
    try
    {
        // do some background work
    }      
    catch
    {
        //
    } 
}
```

`Parallel.ForEach()` looks like this:

```
startfunction()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 250), i => WorkThreadFunction(i));
}

public void WorkThreadFunction(int x)
{
    try
    {
        // do some background work
    }      
    catch
    {
        //
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 While your answer is good, you've changed the behavior of `startfunction`. Now `startfunction` will wait for all threads synchronously. That may/maynot be intended behavior. I thought it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The OP is not clear on what type of "notification" he is looking for, so I went for the simplest. I.e. just wait.

Answer (score -2):

In your main thread you can do something like this...

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

// CREATE THREADS and add them to the list of threads

while (threads.Any(x => x.IsAlive))
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

Console.WriteLine("done");
```

Essentially, keep track of the threads and check their status every now and then in a way that doesn't block the main thread.

Comment: Polling the threads is actually not all that great. I think there are better ways to address the OP's question anyway, but if one is to use the above approach, instead of the `while` loop shown I would just use `Thread.Join()`. That is: `foreach (Thread thread in threads) thread.Join()`. It's simpler, doesn't require scanning the entire list of `Thread` instances every half-second, and will exit the thread immediately instead of having to wait up to half a second (or whatever the interval is) to learn that all the threads are done.

Comment: @NidhiSharma You've picked a wrong answer. Well, it's your choice to choose whatever helped you. But unfortunately this is unlikely to help someone in future. In fact this will promote bad practice. So downvoted.

Comment: Actually i implemented this one and it was working fine so selected it as right answer but later on implemented peter's Answer and that was working better so selected his answer. As i mentioned in first line of my question that i am New to threading so picked first answer which worked :)